# How to count Consecutive Maximum Occurrence of a word in an item of a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, count, counter

I'm trying to implement a code that will count the longest run of a word in an item of a list

```
    for_example = ['smaplakidfsmapsmapsmapuarebeautiful']
```

so in this example, it will be 3 because smap was repeated 3 times so is there is a code that does this task for me no matter what the word is.

Comment: Why is `for_example` a list. Do you expect it to have more than one item? If so, will the result be the max in each item or the max for the list?

Comment: for each item thanks for asking

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/return-maximum-occurring-character-in-the-input-string/

Comment: this post talk about how to get how much is repeated but not in a Consecutive way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
If you have a list of items, you can call the function like this:

```py
[countMaxConsecutiveOccurences(item, 'smap') for item in items]
```

```py
def countMaxConsecutiveOccurences(item, s):
    i = 0
    n = len(s)
    current_count = 0
    max_count = 0
    while i < len(item):
        if item[i:i+n] == s:
            current_count += 1
            max_count = max(max_count, current_count)
            i += n
        else:
            i += 1
            current_count = 0     
    return max_count

countMaxConsecutiveOccurences('smaplakidfsmapsmapsmapuarebeautiful', 'smap')
```

Comment: Yes but in this code you specified 'smap' i want the Consecutive Maximum Occurrence of a word no matter what the word is.

Comment: Do you mean you want the maximum consecutive substring?

Comment: your phrasing of "a certain word" gave me the impression that it was an argument -- you may want to edit that int he question.

Comment: Yes of course I understand the misunderstanding.

Comment: How do identify a word ? Anything could be a word...

Comment: you can run this for Each substrings in the string until the max is bigger the the length of chosen word is bigger the the length of the whole string/the max count